# MySQL Installation: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

Tags: mysql, linux

Tried to install MySQL on Ubuntu, with these 3 commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mysql-server
mysql_secure_installation
```

When running the last command, it asks for the password for the root account. After I enter it, I got the following error:

```
Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root:
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I have checked and apparently there is no mysqld.sock file anywhere.

Is there anything else I should run that I haven't yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know there are a lot of descriptions about this error on the internet, but there seems to be many causes for that, and all of them seems linked to installation.

In my case, I found out my "sudo" access had some issues. After I've corrected them, I've uninstalled everything and installed again, and everything seems to work fine now.